# Debugging cplex model

Tags: modeling, cplex

I implemented a cplex model and I am convinced that the model should allow a better solution on a specific instance. However, when I impose the variable values of the solution onto the model, it returns no solution.

Is there a simple way to find "the inequality that makes the solution infeasible"? I think, I once had cplex give me a violated inequality?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CPLEX has a conflict refiner. The instructions for invoking it are at [How to invoke the conflict refiner](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/infeas_unbd/conflict_refiner/04_invoke.html).

Answer (score 8):

With CPLEX_CMD : execute the following commands

```
read(your_problem.lp)      

optimize 

tools

conflict

display

conflict 

all
```

This will give you the smallest set of equations that make the problem infeasible.

Comment: May the downvoter explain the downvote ? The set of command lines provides exactly what OP is asking if I am not crazy. I use this all the time.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but the question is how to find out why a particular hypothetical solution is infeasible, not why the model is infeasible. (The model in fact seems to be feasible, put possibly missing an optimal solution.)

Comment: @prubin thank you for your feedback you are  right. In this case I would add the variable values (or a subset of them) as constraints of the program and follow the same procedure.