# No solution found from n MIP starts

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cplex, c++

Currently, I am working on the implementation of a **MILP formulation** with lazy constraints for an optimization problem, and I am using the **MIP Start** strategy. I am generating the **integer feasible solution** to the MIP Start through a **heuristic**, the solution is feasible for all possible lazy constraints. However, whenever I pass the integer solution to the MIP Start the Cplex returns the following **warning**:

```
Warning: No solution found from 481 MIP starts.
```

And the Cplex begins to solve the problem **without** using the provided integer solution. In all [MIP Start effort level](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.ide.help/refcppopl/html/enumerations/IloCplex_MIPStartEffort.html), the same behavior is presented. Also, as recommended by this [IBM Support webpage](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/416477), I am setting the Cplex parameters:

- Presolve reduce to 1:

  cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Param::Preprocessing::Reduce, 1);
- Symmetry to 0.

  cplex.setParam(IloCplex::Param::Preprocessing::Symmetry, 0);

and again, the same behavior is presented. It seems that the MIP start is not accepting the provided solution. But I do not know why. I would like to know if anyone already experienced this. For more information, I am using the programming language C++ with Cplex studio 12.10 and Concert technology.

**UPDATE 1:** The approached optimization problem is a variant of the VRP, and the MILP formulation is very similar to the [VRP Vehicle flow formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem#Vehicle_flow_formulations). And regarding the feasible solution, it is composed of one customer per route.

Comment: Could you add more information about the constraints being added to the model and the MIP start solution passed to CPLEX?

Comment: Sure, I added an update to the question. Thank you.

Comment: Are you supplying a full solution, or only values for some variables? If you fix all the variables at their starting values (by setting their upper and lower bounds) and try to solve the model, does CPLEX declare it infeasible?

Comment: @prubin, Yes the solution is feasible and complete, and I checked it using the strategy recommended by you in this question: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/check-which-constraints-are-violated-concert-cplex-studio-12-10-c?noredirect=1#comment4088_3418

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of internet research and coding debugging, I could finally solve the problem. The problem was on the way that I passed the solution to the Cplex MIP Start. Below follows an example of how I was passing the solution to the Cplex MIP Start, where `x_var` is a matrix of variables, `x_start_val` is a matrix of values, and `cplex` is an object of class `IloCplex`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) 
        cplex.addMIPStart(x_var[i][j], x_start_val[i][j]);
```

However, after carefully reading the documentation of the function `addMIPStart` from the class `IloCplex` in this [IBM Support Webpage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex.html#method_addMIPStart). I found the following information:

> There is no method to create a MIP start from a multidimensional array
> of variables. In order to create a MIP start from a multidimensional
> array of variables, you first must copy all those variables into a
> flat array.

Therefore, to pass the solution in `x_start_val` to the MIP Start, I would need to change the previous code:

```
IloNumVarArray startVar(env);
IloNumArray startVal(env);
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
             startVar.add(x_var[i][j]);
             startVal.add(x_start_val[i][j]);
    }
cplex.addMIPStart(startVar, startVal);
startVal.end();
startVar.end();
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your solution is indeed feasible and that your lazy constraints are correctly coded, the most likely explanation is that the order of your variables is inconsistent between your heuristic and CPLEX's input.

Comment: Thank for the answer, but what are you trying to say is that there is some error in the piece of code that 'translates' the heuristic solution to a CPLEX's input?

Comment: Yes, that would be my best guess, a mismatch in the order/number/names of variables.

Comment: You were right, please check the question's answer to see in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to disable all the presolve?

I don't remember which version it stoped, but in some early 12. versions of cplex there was a bug that did not disable some presolve function that allowed the solver to remove some constraints/variables it found unnecessary. Sometimes this could lead to infeasibility, or suboptimal solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, I followed the recommendations presented on this web page (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/416477), where is recommended to set the presolve reduce to 1 and symmetry to 0. But I will check the other presolvers as well.